Teller API initialization in JSX
I am attempting to initialize teller-react-connect config to my application. But the ready status doesn't toggle as true when setting up the configs.
I have converted the code from this documentation to JSX: https://github.com/tellerhq/teller-connect-react/blob/master/examples/hooks.tsx
Anyone know something I don't?
